# How do I create a scrolling function that targets an h1 element, and then changes the color of that element when it reaches a different section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My current function works by changing the color to black when the scroll number reaches 100. However, how do I target the js to change the color to black when the scroll reaches the p tag? I think my code is close to being able to do this, I'm just not sure how to alter my if statement to target specific sections rather than a number?

```html
<!-- html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scrolling Function Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
            <h1 class='test-title'>Testing title</h1>
        </header>
 
        

    <br>

        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni excepturi error facere sed quas repellat perferendis, 
        enim cumque, voluptatem mollitia porro consectetur dicta officiis itaque, quae adipisci accusamus quibusdam amet eligendi. 
        Ad delectus iure exercitationem accusamus ea nihil magni doloribus, inventore aut molestias repudiandae hic non in asperiores 
        dolor! Repellat blanditiis accusantium rem iure, molestias doloremque quidem. Facere nisi libero error aut hic tempora quidem 
        voluptate, omnis, nihil molestias, animi quia distinctio? Vel beatae, at dolore, laboriosam rem voluptatibus sunt illo obcaecati
        modi iure sed odio voluptatum, numquam accusantium quibusdam tenetur velit aliquid! Ad animi sunt ratione suscipit totam tenetur 
        quia exercitationem excepturi doloribus vero nostrum, sapiente alias iste nam doloremque voluptatum consectetur reiciendis omnis 
        tempora? Esse quaerat molestias hic beatae ipsum, recusandae odio nobis sit quo in veniam aperiam, itaque facilis rerum eum. 
        Exercitationem architecto nulla dolor nemo eius neque ipsam omnis provident porro laborum eaque, totam quos. Obcaecati totam 
        doloribus recusandae aliquam quisquam consequuntur soluta impedit dolorum quam at? Aliquid, reiciendis. Eveniet, earum aliquid 
        sapiente quo voluptates velit nemo, distinctio architecto sint tenetur itaque! Dolore, sapiente debitis. Dolorum tempore, sunt 
        quam eos praesentium molestiae animi delectus architecto ipsa voluptate repudiandae odio error nulla. Nihil, accusamus aperiam! 
        Magni iure ea nulla veniam, provident quae ex nobis saepe veritatis dolor! Minus omnis totam quasi nam illum explicabo non ipsum 
        quibusdam iste sed facere officia, quia, minima sint debitis. Sequi consectetur assumenda tempore autem hic nihil alias! Illum natus 
        totam reiciendis adipisci voluptatibus nostrum! Ratione illo nulla provident, laborum quaerat voluptas.
    </p>
  


    <!-- css -->
<style>
    /*css to set position of title*/
        body {
            min-height: 1400px;
        }

        p {
            color: black;
            margin-top: 700px;
        }
    
        .test-title {
            position: fixed;
            color: white;
            background-color: darkblue;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        
        .test-title.active {
            color: black;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

    </style>
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
        const titleEffect = document.querySelector('.test-title');
        
        
        //scroll function
        window.onscroll = function() {
            let top = window.scrollY;
            console.log(top);
            if (top >= '100') {
                titleEffect.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                titleEffect.classList.remove('active');
            }
        } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"I'm just not sure how to alter my if statement to target specific sections rather than a number?"_ - wrong way around. What you would need to do, is get the starting position on the y axis of your section/target element, and then replace the static `100` with that value ... (But you should of course rather use the Intersection Observer API, as mentioned in the recently given answer.)

Answer (score 0):

what your'e looking for is the intersection observer API.

by using it you'll be able to use a callback function which will manipulate your title element color when your `<p>` tag will be in view.

check it our [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: @SunlessShadow if my answer helped please mark it as the accepted answer.